# Comparing contents of 2 array lists

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

The purpose of this program is to import 2 files. A plaintext file and a dictionary plaintext file.

The program should search through the files and compare the words and print out anyones that do not match i.e the misspelled ones.

I have used the scanner to read through and put each line into an array (the dictionary is set out in lines) but I cannot figure out how to compare the two array lists against each other.

Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.io.File;    
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Dictionary {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList <String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList <String> dict = new ArrayList<String>();

    File inputFile = new File(args [0]);
    File inputDictionary = new File(args [1]);

    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    Scanner inDict = new Scanner(inputDictionary);

    while(in.hasNext()) {
        String word = in.next();
        words.add(word);    
    }

    while (inDict.hasNextLine()) {
        String correctWord = inDict.nextLine();
        dict.add(correctWord);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use a loop and `dict.contains`

Comment: What about using Apache Commons - CollectionUtils and do: `ArrayList mispelledWords = CollectionUtils.disjunction(words, dict);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
for(String word : words){ //loop for words
   if(!dict.contains(word))  //check if dict contain word
     System.out.println(word); //print it if dict doesnt have word
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cycle through every word in the words Arraylist and see if it is contained in the dict Arraylist.

```
boolean[] misspelled = new boolean[words.size()];
int i = 0;
for (String word : words) {
    misspelled[i] = !dict.contains(word);
    i++;
}
```

This defines an array of booleans that keeps track of all the misspelled words and if a word at a particular index is not contained within the dictionary list, than the boolean at that index is set to true, meaning that that word is not spelled right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the two `ArrayList` and compare them.

```
   for(int i = 0; i<words.size();i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<dict.size(); j++){
            if(words.get(i).equals(dict.get(j))){
                // they are equivalent strings
            }else{
                // not equivalent
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about using enhanced for-loops instead?

Comment: @Ascalonian that works as well. I prefer traditional for loops because the give you more control allowing you to get/change the iterating variable.